# Mac M1 Pro pyodbc [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

Environment

Python: 3.9.7
pyodbc: 4.0.34
OS: Mac (M1)
DB:
driver: ODBC
Issue

I have Mac M1 Pro, trying to connect to Azure SQL server using pyodbc. my settings works well on my previous windows base laptop, but not here. This is the error I get when trying to connect to sql server using pyodbc

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
but file exists.

I checked

```
lipo -info /opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.1.1.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib
```

returns:

```
Non-fat file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.1.1.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib is architecture: arm64
```

libmsodbcsql.18.dylib exists in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.1.1.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib, but there is a shortcut in /opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib.` I also changed Driver to the above address, still same result.

This was my process:
I have installed ODBC V18 and brew using Microsoft instruction. when I run this on terminal works fine:

```
odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.11
DRIVERS............: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /opt/homebrew/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/user_name/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
(base) User_name@TMDLXNPPVJ4J ~ % cat /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

`pyodbc.drivers()` returns [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]

I have also did these:

```
brew install unixodbc
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/include"
pip install pyodbc
```

`isql -v -k "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx"` works by the way

Please help. thanks